# Java Spring Security 6 Websocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

First, I tried to make a clean simple project with websockets without security, here's the code:

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public Controller(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @PostMapping("/sendLong")
    public void sendLong(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/long", id);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
    
}
```

Client side:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.5.0/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stompjs@2.3.3/lib/stomp.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');
        const stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);
        
        stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/long', (message) => {
                console.log('Received: ' + message.body);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

At this stage, everything works perfectly, but when I connect security, I get an error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNeiv.png)

here's the security code:

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Websocket security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketSecurity
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    AuthorizationManager<Message<?>> messageAuthorizationManager(MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.Builder messages) {
        messages
                .anyMessage().permitAll();
        return messages.build();
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to allow access to endpoints for all users, but the connection does not work, I tried different methods like:

```
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        AuthorizationManager<Message<?>> myAuthorizationRules = AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.anonymous();
        AuthorizationChannelInterceptor authz = new AuthorizationChannelInterceptor(myAuthorizationRules);
        AuthorizationEventPublisher publisher = new SpringAuthorizationEventPublisher(this.context);
        authz.setAuthorizationEventPublisher(publisher);
        registration.interceptors(new SecurityContextChannelInterceptor(), authz);
    }
```

As far as I understand, this disables csrf, but none of this helps, what could be the problem?

Also, in the future, I plan to connect a JWT filter. How is the JWT token obtained when working with WebSocket on Spring Boot 3 and Security 6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is basic auth implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/", "/ws/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
        User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("123").roles("USER").build();
    UserDetails user2 =
        User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("123").roles("USER").build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(List.of(user, user2));
  }
}
```

It uses form login. If you want to see all source codes check it out:
https://github.com/gurkanucar/spring-boot-secure-websocket